# How to use angles to calculate the dimensions of a pyramid

Tags: geometry

I am having some trouble with general trigonometry to calculate dimensions for the pyramid shown in the photo below.

Basically, let's say that my:

**HFOV** = `75 degrees`

**VFOV** = `47 degrees`

**DFOV** = '82 degrees'

I also have the `x` and `y` dimensions of the `image plane`.

How would I find the height of the pyramid?

[image]

Comment: what about DFOV? Is it 90 degrees?

Comment: I have it as 82 degrees.  (updated my question)  Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what kind of pyramid is this? You may have too many or too less parameters. Is the center right above the center of the rectangle?

Comment: What do you mean by x and y dimensions of the image plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a line from the lens to the center of the pyramid.  The diagonal of the base is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  You form a right triangle from the corner of the base to the center of the base to the lens with the angle at the lens being $41^\circ$.  The half diagonal divided by the height of the pyramid is $\tan 41^\circ$, so $h=\frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2\tan 41^\circ}$